# Chain of commands

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I need to execute several commands in a specific order but before I excute the main command, another command needs to be executed first and in some situations there are more commands that also need to be executed last.

To achieve this I build an extended chain of resposibility. It does not only have a post-command but also a pre-command. The main command in the middle is the one that a user sees in a menu.

```
internal abstract class Command
{
    public Command Pre { get; set; }

    public Command Post { get; set; }

    public int Execute()
    {
        var executedCommandCount = 0;

        if (Pre != null)
        {
            var preResult = Pre.Execute();
            if (preResult == 0) { return executedCommandCount; }
            executedCommandCount += preResult;
        }

        if (!ExecuteCore())
        {
            return executedCommandCount;
        }

        executedCommandCount++;

        if (Post != null)
        {
            var postResult = Post.Execute();
            if (postResult == 0) { return executedCommandCount; }
            executedCommandCount += postResult;
        }

        return executedCommandCount;
    }

    protected abstract bool ExecuteCore();
}
```

Test commands:

```
class FirstCommand : Command
{
    protected override bool ExecuteCore()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class MainCommand : Command
{
    protected override bool ExecuteCore()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class LastCommand : Command
{
    protected override bool ExecuteCore()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var mainCommand = new MainCommand
{
    Pre = new FirstCommand(),
    Post = new LastCommand()
};

var executedCommandCount = mainCommand.Execute(); // 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not implement WPF's `ICommand`? That way you could use them in command bindings, and if you're not using WPF, you could still attach them to click handlers and use their `CanExecute` method to determine whether to enable or disable a menu item.

It's not immediately obvious why a command's `Execute` method would return anything. Having a parameterized command (like `ICommand` has) could be used to eliminate the need for that `bool` return value. It's not clear what the `int` value might be used for either (other than debugging?).

The setters for `Pre` and `Post` should be `protected` IMO; they have no business on the type's public interface.

The `null` checks indicate that not all implementations actually need a `Pre` or a `Post` command: to me this is starting to smell a bit.

Seems a more robust and flexible design would be a simple `ICommand` with decorators - here over a classic `DelegateCommand` base class implementing `ICommand`:

```
public class PreExecuteCommandDecorator : DelegateCommand
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand _command;
    private readonly Action<object> _action;

    public PreExecuteCommandDecorator(DelegateCommand command, Action<object> action)
    {
        _command = command;
        _action = action;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _command.CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public override void ExecuteCore(object parameter)
    {
        _action.Invoke(parameter);
        _command.Execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Similarly:

```
public class PostExecuteCommandDecorator : DelegateCommand
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand _command;
    private readonly Action<object> _action;

    public PostExecuteCommandDecorator(DelegateCommand command, Action<object> action)
    {
        _command = command;
        _action = action;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _command.CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public override void ExecuteCore(object parameter)
    {
        _command.Execute(parameter);
        _action.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

That way you could build your "chain of command" in a much cleaner way IMO - especially if you're building an actual "chain" with pre-commands that have their own pre and post commands that have their own pre and post commands that have their own pre... well you get the idea.

Comment: I like the decorator idea. Currently I use this in a console application but later I'm going to upgrade this to WPF so using the right objects from the beginning would save actually a lot of work. (it's a nuget automation tool that for example needs to update nuspec files before executing pack etc.)

Comment: This has only one flaw: if one command fails the next one must not be executed... I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I can throw exceptions :-]

Comment: Was going to say, "that would be an exception's job" ;-)

Comment: What do think of the idea if I created only one decorator with a private constructor but with two factory methods allowing me to create either a pre- or Post- decorator?

Comment: Sounds like a plan - depending on what the pre/post actions actually are (cross-cutting concerns?), and whether you're using DI (and an IoC framework that supports it), consider implementing *interceptors* - they're pretty much like decorators, with pre/post execute hooks.

Comment: They're actually mostly tightly coupled to the main command, working for example with the same file name but I'll keep the interceptors in mind for another time. I see they can by really useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is my *final* implementation where I use the WPF's `ICommand`, a decorator for composition and two factory extensions to chain the commands.

```
internal class LinkedCommand : ICommand 
{
    private readonly ICommand _pre;
    private readonly ICommand _post;

    public LinkedCommand(ICommand pre, ICommand post)
    {
        _pre = pre;
        _post = post;
    }   

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object arg)
    {
        return _pre.CanExecute(arg) && _post.CanExecute(arg);
    }

    public void Execute(object arg)
    {
        _pre.Execute(arg);
        _post.Execute(arg);
    }
}
```

Two factory extensions:

```
public static class CommandComposition
{ 
    public static ICommand Pre(this ICommand current, ICommand pre)
    {
        return new LinkedCommand(pre, current);
    }

    public static ICommand Post(this ICommand current, ICommand post)
    {
        return new LinkedCommand(current, post);
    }
}
```

Example commands:

```
class FirstCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object arg) => true;

    public void Execute(object arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First");
    }
}

class MainCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object arg) => true;

    public void Execute(object arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main");
    }
}

class LastCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object arg) => true;

    public void Execute(object arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Last");
    }
}
```

Now the usage is nice and clean:

```
var mainCommand = new MainCommand().Pre(new FirstCommand()).Post(new LastCommand());
mainCommand.Execute(null);
```

```
First
Main
Last
```